# ScalaByExample - receiveWithin method explanation

Tags: scala

I am sorry if this is a really simple question. Could someone explain how the case syntax statements perform as function arguments to receiveWithin. I am lost since I thought arguments should be with the ().

```
    receiveWithin ((closing.getTime() - new Date().getTime())) {
      case Offer(bid, client) =>
        if (bid >= maxBid + bidIncrement) {
          if (maxBid >= minBid) maxBidder ! BeatenOffer(bid)
            maxBid = bid; maxBidder = client; client ! BestOffer
          } else {
            client ! BeatenOffer(maxBid)
          }
      case Inquire(client) =>
        client ! Status(maxBid, closing)
      case TIMEOUT =>
        if (maxBid >= minBid) {
          val reply = AuctionConcluded(seller, maxBidder)
          maxBidder ! reply; seller ! reply
        } else {
          seller ! AuctionFailed
        }
        receiveWithin(timeToShutdown) {
          case Offer(_, client) => client ! AuctionOver
          case TIMEOUT => running = false
        }
    }
```

The receiveWithin method of class Actor takes as parameters a time span
given in milliseconds and a **function** that processes messages in the mailbox.
**The function is given by a sequence of cases** that each specify a pattern and
an action to perform for messages matching the pattern. The receiveWithin
method selects the first message in the mailbox which matches one of these
patterns and applies the corresponding action to it.

Comment: FYI, Scala Actors are no longer available Scala 2.11.x, you should use Akka Actors going forward: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html